# How to make a deponent passive in meaning?

Tags: syntax, passive-voice, deponent-verbs

I was thinking about the verb *sequi*, a deponent which means *to follow*. I was wondering, how do you put the deponent into a passive form?

So is it possible to translate the following sentences into Latin with the verb *sequi*?

- *I'm being followed*
- *I had been followed*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question!

I am not aware of a possibility of passivizing such a structure.
Instead, I suggest two ways around this:

- Use a different verb.
  Depending on context, perhaps *comitare*, *haerere*, or *insistere* could replace *sequi*.
  With a non-deponent verb you can form passives as usual.
- Use a pronoun meaning "someone".
  Although *aliquis me sequitur* might not be exactly what you are after, it's pretty close.

Comment: As @Joonas Ilmavirta suggests in his example, it's usual to invert the sentence for such usages. If you were looking to represent the unpleasant modern crime of 'stalking', you might use _insidior_, meaning to lie in wait, or wait for an opportunity. Martial XII, 14, 10 has _Tuscis . . . insidiemur apris_, 'let's stalk wild boars'.

Comment: Hmm, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insisto#Latin) says that _insisto_ is "impersonal in the passive".

Comment: @BenKovitz Have you checked whether [more reliable dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) insist that it's impersonal?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Not yet…