# More verbs like "mensuro", active verb derived from deponent?

Tags: participle, deponent-verbs

I just read on Wiktionary that the Late/Vulgar verb [*mensuro*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensuro#Latin) (I measure) comes from Classical [*mensura*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensura#Latin) (a measure or measurement), which comes from [*mensus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensus#Latin), the perfect participle of the deponent verb [*metior*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metior#Latin) (I measure). This provides a way to express the meaning of *metior* in a passive sense: *mensurari* (to be measured).

Are there other non-deponent verbs formed from perfect participles of deponent verbs like this? Is it a normal, reasonable way to make a verb? If so, it might provide a secondary answer to [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4658/118), about how to give a passive meaning to a deponent verb.

I tried deriving such a verb: *sequor* > *secutus* > *secuturo,* but a quick search turns that up only as the dative/ablative of the future participle [*secuturus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secuturus#Latin), and no *secuturare* (which does sound very clumsy to my ear).